# How do I check number of processes per CPU using zabbix?

Tags: zabbix

By default zabbix is able to check the total number of processes on a machine and triggers and error if these are above 300.

Clearly this doesn't work well for bigger machines. I do have a server with 32 codes and obviously 300 processes would be nothing for this machine.

I do want to change this rule to trigger a warning if the number of process per CPU is greater than 300.

This trigger is inside linux template and is named "Too many processes on {HOST.NAME}", the default values is `"{Template OS Linux:proc.num[].avg(5m)}>300"`

I tried to write something like `{Template OS Linux:proc.num[].avg(5m)}/{Template OS Linux:system.cpu.num}>300` but it seems that zabbix (2.2) doesnt like this trigger expression.

```
Incorrect trigger expression. Check expression part starting from "/{Template OS Linux:system.cpu.num}>300".
```

What is the correct way to re-configure this check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax for item references in trigger expressions is:

```
{host:item.func()}
```

In your particular case, the `func()` part is missing after `system.cpu.num`, so the correct expression would be:

```
{Template OS Linux:proc.num[].avg(5m)}/{Template OS Linux:system.cpu.num.last()}>300
```

Note that if you are not comfortable with editing trigger expressions by hand, you can use the "Add" button on the right of expression which brings up a simple wizard:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this as I wasn't able to find it in the docs. Now I do have another problem, it seems that the status of this item appears to be "Not Supported", if I click it it goes to Disabled and back to Not Supported.

Comment: @sorin: The trigger expression syntax is described in detail at https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/config/triggers/expression .

Comment: @sorin: Regarding the item being not supported, which of these two items do you mean? Which version of Zabbix agent are you using and do you have SELinux enabled?